# revert state to default props in ES6

Tags: reactjs

using the following ES6 syntax, what's the best way to revert the state to default status when reset is called? or another solution would be seamlessly reload the component (I read that forceUpdate is not a good option)

```
class XYZ extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(),
    this.state = {
     ...
    }
  }

  reset() {
    //I need to revert to default props here
  }
}

XYZ.propTypes = {
  ...
}

XYZ.defaultProps = {
  ...
}

export default XYZ
```

technically I can implement the reset like:

```
reset() {
  if (this.mounted) {
    this.setState(()=> {
      const newState = {
        anchorStandards: {writing: [], reading: []},
        gradeLevels: {gradeLevels: []}
      }
      this.props.onFilterChange(newState)
      return newState
    })
  }
}
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to call this.defaultPros

Answer (score 1):

Implement a `getDefaultState(props)` function, then call it both in `constructor(props)` and `reset()`.

For example:

```
getDefaultState(props) {
  return { importantState: props.importantState }
}

constructor(props) {
  this.state = this.getDefaultState(props)
}

reset() {
  this.setState(this.getDefaultState(this.props))
}
```

With this approach, the parent component doesn't need to know anything, and the code that determines the relevant props and initial state is only written once.

Comment: the reason I was using the XYZ.defaultProps is:
warning.js:36 Warning: getDefaultProps was defined on XYZ, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Use a static property to define defaultProps instead. So you are write if I was using the getDefaultState I could use that syntax

Comment: Well, yes. Thing is, `getDefaultProps()` existed in older React versions, so now it warns you because it thinks you're making a mistake. **That said, have this in mind**: if a Component is modifying its own data (as you are doing with `reset()`, it should be called `state`, not `props`. React calls externally given information `props`, and internally decided information `state`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/5fhdLcey/

**Parent Element**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        name: "Pablo",
    };
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({
        name: undefined,
    });
  }

    render() {
    return(
        <div>
        <HelloWidget name={this.state.name} reset={this.reset} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**Child Element**

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
        <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.props.reset} >Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HelloWidget.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
  reset: React.PropTypes.func,
}

HelloWidget.defaultProps = {
    name: "Friend",
}
```